# Node.js: SyntaxError: Unexpected token : while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, filter, ejs

I am trying to apply filter to EJS using Node.JS and I am getting the below error. I want the message content to be displayed in uppercase.

```
D:\Apps\Templating\ejs>node server.js
D:\Apps\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:470
      throw e;
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token : while compiling ejs
    at Function (native)
    at Object.Template.compile (D:\Apps\node_m
odules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:460:12)
    at Object.compile (D:\Apps\node_modules\ej
s\lib\ejs.js:288:16)
    at handleCache (D:\Apps\node_modules\ejs\l
ib\ejs.js:147:16)
    at Object.exports.render (D:\Apps\node_mod
ules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:315:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Apps\Templating\
ejs\server.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

This is my code- server.js:

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
var template = "<%=: message | upcase %>";
console.log(ejs.render(template,{message : 'hello ejs with filter'}));
```

I have installed ejs using the package manager and it is working for normal scripts with out filters(:). EJS version downloaded is the latest- 2.3.3 and node version is 0.12.4.

```
npm install ejs
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<%=:` isn't a valid construct, and `ejs` also doesn't support filters (like that).

Comment: ejs do support filters like this. Please check this. https://github.com/tj/ejs

Comment: When you install `ejs` you install [this module](https://github.com/mde/ejs). The page you're refering to states: _"NOTE: Version 2 of EJS makes some breaking changes with this version (notably, removal of the filters feature)"_.

Comment: Yes. I found out that just now. I am not sure of the reson for removal. But it was a very handy feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current version of `ejs` (v2.3.3) doesn't support filters, which were removed from version 2. If you want to use filters, you need to install a 1.x version:

```
$ npm i ejs@1.x
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out this now. EJS made some changes from version 2 onwards including removal of filter feature. 
https://github.com/tj/ejs

Answer (score 0):

in ejs v2 you have to put the code without = or - if there is normal code or function but not an object 
if you have an object you have to start with = or -
Complies with the Express view system
Static caching of intermediate JavaScript
Unbuffered code for conditionals etc `<% code %>`
Escapes html by default with `<%= code %>`
Unescaped buffering with `<%- code %>`
Supports tag customization
Filter support for designer-friendly templates
Includes
Client-side support
Newline slurping with `<% code -%>` or `<% -%>` or `<%= code -%>` or `<%- code -%>`
see more information here :
https://github.com/tj/ejs